# Global.asax Application_Start not firing when debugging, but fires in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I'm using Application_start to set my routes in an asp.net webforms application.  It was working fine, then I cloned the repo on a new machine and it stopped working.  The event never fires, and the routes never get set. So I end up with a lot of 404 errors.

I even went as far as to throw an exception in the event to make sure it's not firing and the exception was never thrown.

However, it works when I publish the application.

Comment: Which environment are you running locally in? Is it IIS?

Comment: IIS Express on development machine & IIS installed on publishing server may treat some significant parts of your repo differently. If you encountering same error again, post it on your question both error details and exception output if any.

Comment: @sachin out of VS it's in IIS express, when I publish it locally it it's running on IIS7

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto that's the odd thing, there are no exceptions. It just acts as if global.asax doesn't exist.

Comment: @Smeegs So you're saying that it gets called if running on IIS7(when published on local) but doesn't when running from VS using IISExpress?

Comment: yep, that's what's happening

Comment: Did you try stopping IISExpress manually before launching using F5 from VS?
or just try one thing Go to Web section of the properties of your web project
check 'Enable Edit and Continue' at the bottom

Comment: Sorry, chat is blocked by my company proxy :(.  I did try stopping iis express manually.  It's worth noting that nothing was changed in global.asax.  I'm not waiting for changes to load, this was in the repo when I cloned it.

Comment: It is VS behaving as weird as it can then ;) I'm just leaving the answer in case it could be helpful to someone else facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you **try stopping IISExpress manually** before launching the application from Visual Studio.

Or just Go to Web section of the properties of your web project and check **'Enable Edit and Continue'** at the bottom.

> When you choose Edit and Continue then we recycle the ASP.Net Web
>   Server process on every debug run (it is needed for the Edit &
>   Continue functionality to work)…  This way although you will see very
>   marginal degrade in your performance you will still be able to debug
>   your Application_Start() methods…

This should help you understand why you are facing the issue:

> The reason behind this is that we do not kill the ASP.Net Web Server
>   process after your every debug run and hence Application_Start() is
>   not fired every time.  There is a good reason why we do so…  Starting
>   ASP.Net Web Server process is an expensive task and in most of the
>   scenarios recycling this process after every debug would adversely
>   impact your performance…  If you do not want to debug your
>   Application_Start() method then probably you do not need to have the
>   process restart and save performance most of the time…

The details are in the article linked below:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2007/12/13/workaround-debugging-global-aspx-cs-application_start-with-asp-net-web-server-within-visual-studio/